# Is there an valid proguard rule for RxJava and FasterXML?

Tags: android, proguard, rx-java, kotlin, fasterxml

Now the only problem stopping me from using kotlin in production is that I can't find a correct proguard file for it.

What I used:

> 1.Kotlin
>
> 2.Anko
>
> 3.Jackson-Kotlin-module

Here's the warning message:

```
:app:proguardRelease
Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentCircularArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentSequencedCircularArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpmcArrayQueueConsumerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpmcArrayQueueProducerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpscLinkedQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpmcArrayQueueConsumerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpmcArrayQueueProducerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: rx.internal.util.unsafe.UnsafeAccess: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: there were 41 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
```

Comment: Please describe your problem. What rules you tried, what didn't work and what were the errors?

Comment: None of the errors is directly connected with Kotlin. Does it work if you replace Kotlin code with Java?

Comment: @AndreyBreslav The whole project is written in Kotlin, I cannot replace it  with Java.

Comment: This is Not related to Kotlin, Just add following lines in you proguard. --
 -dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

a better is just to have this aar as a dependency:

https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/RxJavaProGuardRules

Comment: For those who comes with the same problem, I solved finally according with this answer, with additional options handle kotlin reflections

Comment: @Marvin: could you post your proguard file?

Answer (score 28):

It has nothing to do with Kotlin. Ignore the warnings in your proguard file:

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
```

Comment: Thanks you mentioned, it has nth to do with Kotlin .